# IndexOutOfRangeExpection occurs on Dictionary.Add method

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, windows-runtime, indexoutofrangeexception

I am getting an IndexOutOfRange exception while adding values to Generic dictionary (WinRT C#). Below is my code and stack trace of exception.

Code:

```
if (!data.TryGetValue(index, out cells))
{
   cells = new CellCollection();
   data.Add(index, cells);
}
```

Stack trace:

> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
>     at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)

I wouldn't expect this out of range exception occurs while adding. My application uses single thread only. 
I have add values to dictionary and remove it from dictionary using GC.Collect() if not needed. And then add the value if needed.

Can anyone give any suggestion to resolve this exception?

Comment: I guess you're accessing a dictionary in multiple threads without proper synchronization which is not safe. Are you? Edit: I saw in question you mentioned *My application uses single thread only* but make sure you cross check to see if the dictionary slipped to another thread.

Comment: If it's not a concurrency issue (or if you decide you need help solving that) you'll have to post a better question, with a complete-but-concise code example. There's very little information to go on here so far. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information on posting a good code example.

Comment: I agree it sounds like you have multiple threads, as in `.AsParallel()` of `Parallel.ForEach` or something. However, can we see what `TKey`, i.e. the type of `index` is?

Comment: I didn/t use multiple threads in my application. The only thing I did, remove items from the dictionary using Finalize method (Desctructor of the class).  In My dictionary, Tkey is integer (int) type and Tvalue is another generic dicitionary.

Comment: @Selvamz A finalizer is called from a separate thread, so that could be causing issues. (Also: never ever access managed objects from a finalizer. It's for use with unmanaged objects only.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks for your update. But i want to remove items those not needed from dictionary without spending separate time to remove. So can you suggest any other way to do this? Or else any way to lock/prevent the dictionary when add/remove item from different thread?

Comment: Your code is incomplete and don't give us a clear understanding of your situation. In this case adding the missing parts like destructors, data types, initializations and other parts in which you access the dictionary is a lot better that thousands words trying to explain the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During a call to `Dictionary<,>.Add` it will sometimes be necessary to allocate a new backing array because the `Count` exceeds the current capacity of the `Dictionary<,>`. When allocating a new managed object (the new array) the garbage collector might set in. Your application is "paused" and garbage collection takes place. Then after garbage is collected, control resumes from where you were inside the `Add` method, and the new backing array is filled with data from the old one.

However, based on your comments to your question above, you have **finalizers**. There must exist an unrelated object (maybe another instance of the same class) that is being finalized. It seems it holds a reference to the same `Dictionary<,>`. During the finalization, your destructor code, you change the state of the `Dictionary<,>`. Then when the main thread resumes control after the garbage collection, the state of the `Dictionary<,>` has been changed, but we were in the middle of a process of adding one new element to that `Dictionary<,>`.

The lesson learned is: Do not write destructors (finalizers). If you do anyway, do not change the state of managed objects that are (can be) referenced from elsewhere (i.e. from "living" objects that will not be collected).

Matthew Watson said it in a comment to your question.